# Why does $\sup \{x_ky_k\}\le\sup x_k\cdot \sup y_k$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $x_n$ and $y_n$ both be bounded sequences. In the answers proving $\lim\sup (x_n \cdot y_n)\le\lim\sup x_n\cdot \lim\sup y_n$, it is said that, in particular,$\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$ $\sup_{k\ge n} \{x_ky_k\}\le\sup_{k\ge n} x_k\cdot \sup_{k\ge n} y_k$. Why is that? Is this a fact\claim\corollary? Something trivial or just something one remembers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably mean this in the context of a positive sequence, since $x_{2k}=-1, x_{2k+1}=-2$ and $y_{2k}=-2, y_{2k+1}=-1$ gives a counterexample otherwise to the fact you quote that $2=\sup_{k\ge n}x_ky_k> \sup_{k\ge n}x_k\cdot\sup_{k\ge n}y_k=1$.

However, in the positive case we notice that we have an inclusion:

$$A=\{x_ky_k\}_k\subseteq \{x_my_n\}_{m,n}=B$$

Now you can prove that $\sup B=(\sup x_m)(\sup y_n)$ directly since clearly we just choose subsequences $n_j$ and $m_\ell$ so that

$$\begin{cases}x_{n_j}\to \sup x_n\\y_{m_\ell}\to \sup y_m\end{cases}.$$

Then noting $x_ny_m\le (\sup x_n)y_m\le \sup x_n\cdot \sup y_m$--which is where we use positivity--you get the result on $B$.

Since $A\subseteq B$ we have that $\sup A\le \sup B$ by monotonicity of the sup function.

Note that even the case of $\limsup$ requires the positivity, since my example from the start has that the limsup and sup are equal on $x_k$ and $y_k$.